# how to get shamsi date [Persian Calendar] in gradle (android-studio)

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

In gradle we can write a method to get the date so we can use it for example 
for android version name suffix .

```
 static def getDate() { return new Date().format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm') }
```

My problem is to get the date in Persian Calendar .